# Differentiate using the chain rule

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Trying to get me head around the chain rule...

Differentiate the following using the chain rule:

$ln({x-1\over x^3})$

so $f(x)ln={1\over x}$

and $f(x){x-1\over x^3}=-{3x-1\over x^3}$

What's the next step?

Comment: Your math looks weird. Can you fix it? What is $f$?

Comment: When you day f(x)ln, do you mean the derivative of ln(x) with respect to x?

Comment: yeah that's what I mean, sorry just started using this

Comment: ok, I think I'm starting to understand this chain rule. How what I use the properties of logarithms to break up this expression into simpler logarithms first?

Answer (score 1):

Your work is strange. What do you mean by $f(x)\ln$?

$\ln(\frac{x-1}{x^{3}})$

Your first step is to take the derivative of the outer function, and leave the argument as the inner function. Since $\frac{d}{dx} \ln(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, we have:

$\frac{1}{ \frac{x-1}{x^{3}}}$

Your second step is to multiply this by the derivative of the inner function. So take the derivative of $\frac{x-1}{x^{3}}$, and multiply it by $\frac{1}{ \frac{x-1}{x^{3}}}$, and simplify reasonably.

Comment: The function $x \mapsto \ln \frac{x-1}{x^{2}}$ is not defined at $x = 0, 1$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're bringing up here.

Comment: 1) Please speak mathematics; and 2) Please formulate your argument more clearly, or you have an option to make it a comment instead. Last but not least, I am not the person who gave you a minus 1.

Comment: Which part of this process is incorrect, and what is the intent of the first comment? This is the standard chain rule and leads to the derivative of the function.

Comment: For someone new to calculus, Jonathan's method is easy to follow for me

Answer (score 1):

To differentiate this using the chain rule, note that $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \ln f(x) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$

In this case, you have $$f(x) = \frac{x-1}{x^3} = \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x^3}$$

Hence, we have $$f'(x) = \frac{3}{x^4} - \frac{2}{x^3}$$

So the derivative of your function is $$\dfrac{\dfrac{3}{x^4} - \dfrac{2}{x^3}}{\dfrac{x-1}{x^3}} = \frac{3-2x}{x(x-1)}$$

---

To see why $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \ln f(x) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ is true, let $g(x) = \ln f(x)$, then by the chain rule $$g'(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)} \cdot f'(x)$$